# Understanding the solution of a problem.

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, measure-theory, proof-verification, proof-explanation

The problem and its solution are given below:

> [image]

But I do not understand the idea of the solution and some detailed steps , like why we take $\mathcal{F}$ in this form and why the absolute continuity definition assures the existence of such $N$ and why in the last line the indices of the summation one time starts from $j=o$ while the other time starts from $j=1$ and why they end at the same $N$ could anyone explain it for me please?

Comment: The idea is that for $r \in [a,b]$, we should have $f(r) = f(a)$ because $$f(r) - f(a) = \int_a^r f'(t)\, dt = \int_a^r 0 dt = 0$$ But of course, the FTC does not hold since $f$ is not continuously differentiable. So estimate the integral with a sum of differences of $f$ over subintervals, and show that you can use $f'(t) = 0$ to estimate the differences over enough of the subintervals to show that the sum can be made as small as desired.

Comment: And why are we considering $x_{j+1}$ and $y_{j}$ in the third line from below ..... what is special about those intervals than the ones with $x_{j}$ and $y_{j}$?@PaulSinclair